# Windows 11 video capture program not recording audio with video

Tags: video, windows, microphone

I'm wondering if the stock video capture program is used solely for video and not audio. Are there other programs that will record video with audio (for Youtube)? Am I missing something here (settings perhaps)?

I'm open to programs other than the Windows 11 camera if that is part of your answer here.

Comment: Windows 11 video capture should capture both audio and video. SO I think you may need to troubleshoot your settings.